# Get data usage WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, traffic

How can I get data usage programmatically on my WP8? I found class `DataUsage` with properties `BytesReceived` and `BytesSent`. But on MSDN I found the following:

> Remarks Windows Phone 8 
>   This API is not implemented and will throw an exception if called.

Perhaps, somebody knows how can I get the traffic usage (for cellular/Wifi connection)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no API to get the overall traffic usage of the phone. Or at least, none available to third-party developers (there's probably some kind of internal API since Data Sense is able to display that information).

Comment: So, if Data Sense can do it (and Nokia Usage Monitor also), it should be the way to get this data. Perhaps, using native c++ and Radio interface layer (RIL)?

Comment: @brave_warrior Microsoft partners (like Nokia) have access to internal APIs that are not exposed to third-party developers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But on Windows Phone market I found Call Credit application (http://www.windowsphone.com/ru-ru/store/app/call-credit/cdd917a0-bef7-df11-9264-00237de2db9e). And it can calculate data, voice and sms usage.

Comment: Or should I contact with Microsoft or Nokia to get possibility to get these data?

Comment: @brave_warrior The app you linked only works for a few mobile operators, and requires the user to type its username and password. Therefore, it probably retrieves the data from the mobile operator's website. If it used an internal Windows Phone API, then it wouldn't be limited and wouldn't need this kind of information.